# How can I force my android device to use front camera in the OpenTok Library?

Tags: apache-flex

I have a tablet with two cameras, one in the front and one i the rear. I'am trying to make a "video-chat client" in Flex with the OpenTok library. I Have installed Adobe Air 2.6 on the device, the app is running properly, but I can't change which camera I wanna use, default is the rear camera. I know that in Adobe Air 3.0 there is support for changing which camera you want to use, but the library doesn't support Air 3.0.

Does anybody know how I can force with device to only use the front camera?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
camera = Camera.open(Camera.getNumberOfCameras() - 1);
camera.startPreview();
```

This should select your front camera.